# Как вывести элементы из Listbox

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

Имеется `ComboBox`, из которого пользователь выбирает строки, которые после этого отображаются на `ListBox`. Хочу эти выбранные элементы вывести через запятую.

Такой вариант:

```
string.Join(", ", listBox1.SelectedItems)
```

выдаёт `System.Windows.Forms.ListBox+SelectedObjectCollection`.
Пытаюсь обратиться к конкретному объекту `ListBox` по индексу:

```
listBox1.Items[1].ToString()
```

получаю `простанство имен.имякласса`, вместо значения, которое хранится по индексу 1.
Что не так?

Comment: Это Winforms? Добавьте тег `winforms` тогда.

Comment: Я так понимаю в listBox1.Items некие объекты ? т.е. не просто string ? тогда если хотите заюзать .ToString() переопределите его в ваше классе, объекты которого грузите в Items, а иначе он по дефолту выдает имя типа вашего класса

Comment: тогда будет можно по идее string.Join(", ", listBox1.Items)

Comment: `string.Join(", ", listBox1.SelectedItems)` => `string.Join(", ", listBox1.SelectedItems.Cast<НужныйТипОбъекта>())` (привет WinForms'у и его ужасным костылям). В случае с `listBox1.Items[1].ToString()` - если у вас там класс, то так и должно быть, обращайтесь значит к свойствам этого класса (`listBox1.Items[1].Свойство`), если у вас там тип по типу `string`, то такого не должно быть.

Comment: @PavelPopov Вы вместо удаления вопроса, лучше бы его подправили, ведь по поводу `listBox1.Items[1].ToString()` у вас одно из решений задачи, описали бы почему так, дописали бы как можно без переопределения `ToString()` поступить и норм, а про `string.Join()` всего лишь надо про каст упомянуть...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Ок, я просто не хотел красть ваш ответ )

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Нужно переопределить ToString() в вашем классе, который вы используете для заполнения Items, иначе по дефолту он выводит наименование типа.
2. Теперь можно джойнить строку как из SelectedItems, так и из Items, НО обязтаельно через Cast к нужному типу(таковы особенности этой коллекции)

   ```
   public class MainForm
   {
        public MainForm()
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(new DataItem
                {
                    Name = "Петя"
                });
            listBox1.Items.Add(new DataItem
                {
                    Name = "Вася"
                });

            var str = string.Join(",", listBox1.Items.Cast<DataItem>());
        }
    }

    class DataItem
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Name;
        }
    }
   ```

Comment: При чем здесь `static void Main`?

Comment: @aepot тестанул на всякий случай(на простом массиве), но открыл консоль. А потом просто дописал лист вместо массива

Comment: Как это отвечает на поставленный вопрос? Вот автор написал, что делает `string.Join(", ", listBox1.SelectedItems)`, но получает `System.Windows.Forms.ListBox+SelectedObjectCollection`. Вы сейчас банально повторили его код, который возвращает кстати [тоже самое](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMvAg.png), что и у него, без объяснений почему так, что надо сделать, как сделать и так далее. Так в чем польза?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ свою идею я пояснил в комменте под вопросов. Да нужно было ее скопировать в ответ и да вы правы бе каста это не работает. Я почему то думал, что так отработает, может путаю с WPF